# QuickTimeX in Applescript / Scripting Bridge

Tags: ruby, applescript, scripting-bridge

I'd like to be able to grab the metadata of the currently playing file in Quicktime X using ScriptingBridge and Ruby, so far I have the following code

```
require 'osx/cocoa'
OSX.require_framework 'ScriptingBridge'

@app = OSX::SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier("com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX")

@app.documents.each do |movie|
  # What now?!
end
```

But I can't find any functions in QuickTime X's applescript dictionary to get the metadata from a `document` object (the same data you can see in QT's 'Show Movie Inspector' HUD) — does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I don't think Quicktime Player X provides this functionality. Shame really!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about if you [download QuickTime Player 7](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/) and use that instead? It wont replace QuickTime Player X and has many features that X does not (although you'll need a pro serial number to access some of the features from the GUI). Apple still make this version available for a good reason!

Alternatively, if you've got as far as writing some Obj-C code, you could go one step further and access the metadata directly, as illustrated [here](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.10/TheInformer/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

A quick inspection of objects can be done with the [Looksee](http://github.com/oggy/looksee) gem - tells you what methods are available on a ruby-object.  I don't know if it will work properly with ScriptingBridge, but it's quick to try.

Comment: Unfortunately Scripting Bridge appears to work by passing the commands directly to the OS X cocoa framework via `method_missing` so looksee, pretty though it is, doesn't help out so much! Sorry!